# What variants in spelling and pronunciation might there be for Polish surname Chorzelewski?

Tags: surnames, poland

What variants in spelling and pronunciation might there be for the Polish surname Chorzelewski?

The name could be Chorelewski also.

My grandmothers maiden name was Chorzelewski here in the US.

My great grandmother spelled it Chorelewski.

They come from very large families in Poland.

Comment: Omg I've been pronouncing it wrong my whole life

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to guess a proper spelling of a Polish surname, there are two useful resources to look at.

The more reliable is the PESEL database, which contains data about every living Polish national. Current data is confidential (there's a statistical summary available, but that only lists top 100 names), but there's an [export from the '90 available](http://www.futrega.org/etc/nazwiska.html). `Chorzelewski` is present 251 times on this list, the other spelling isn't found.

There's also a crowdsourced geographical database of surnames (definitely less trustworthy) at [moikrewni.pl](http://www.moikrewni.pl/mapa/kompletny/chorzelewski.html) (this portal has been taken over by MyHeritage). This lists 120 matches for `Chorzelewski` and 125 for `Chorzelewska` (female form, not present in the PESEL database).

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate: [Chorzelewski](https://translate.google.com/m/translate#auto/pl/Chorzelewski)

Use speaker icon to listen to pronunciation, which sounds like "Hogelevski".